# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I created local database in DB2 called "`TestDB`" then I created table called "`TestTable`".
I found that the table is put under schema name is "`yasmin`".
I am trying to connect to the `DB2` database using `JDBC` but I got this exception

```
    R SQLException information
[1/4/14 11:32:59:289 EST] 0000004d SystemErr     R Error msg: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.TESTTABLE, DRIVER=3.61.86
[1/4/14 11:32:59:290 EST] 0000004d SystemErr     R SQLSTATE: 42704
[1/4/14 11:32:59:290 EST] 0000004d SystemErr     R Error code: -204
[1/4/14 11:32:59:290 EST] 0000004d SystemErr     R com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.TESTTABLE, DRIVER=3.61.86
```

I tried many solutions on the internet Like set schema but unfortunately doesn't work.

This is the JDBC code I used

```
 String urlPrefix = "jdbc:db2:";
        String url;
        String user;
        String password;
        String empNo;                                                              
        Connection con;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        url = urlPrefix + "//127.0.0.1:50000/TestDB";
        user = "db2admin";
        password = "db2admin";
        try 
        {                                                                        
          // Load the driver
          Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");                              
          System.out.println("**** Loaded the JDBC driver");

          // Create the connection using the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
          con = DriverManager.getConnection (url, user, password);                 
          // Commit changes manually

          con.setAutoCommit(false);
          System.out.println("**** Created a JDBC connection to the data source");
          stmt = con.createStatement();   con.createStatement();                                         
          System.out.println("**** Created JDBC Statement object");
          // Execute a query and generate a ResultSet instance

          rs = stmt.executeQuery("select *from TestTable");                   
          System.out.println("**** Created JDBC ResultSet object");
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
          System.err.println("Could not load JDBC driver");
          System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(SQLException ex)                                                      
        {
          System.err.println("SQLException information");
          while(ex!=null) {
            System.err.println ("Error msg: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println ("SQLSTATE: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.err.println ("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex = ex.getNextException(); // For drivers that support chained exceptions
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 15):

As @Mark Rotteveel said, the `-204` error is from a missing object, but it's missing for a reason other than what he said.

It's not found because you did not prefix it with the schema name. You said above that it's in schema `yasmin`, but you're connecting with `db2admin`, so it's trying to look for `db2admin.TestTable`.

```
SELECT * FROM yasmin.TestTable
```

should be what you're looking for.

By default, the search path for schemas is the name of the currently connecting user. You can see what it is using

```
SELECT CURRENT SCHEMA FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

If you want to change it, you can use the [SET SCHEMA](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html) command to change the search path, but usually it's easier just to include the schema name in your query.

Comment: Unfortunately I used this query before but also doesn't work. I tried to set the table schema in db2 to be "db2admin" using query and check current schema using a query. it changed. After that if I browse the table schema its the same "yasmin" doesn't change.

Answer (score 3):

The error [SQLERROR -204, SQLSTATE 42704](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-204_sqlstate_42704.html) is a missing/unknown objectname and it is most likely caused by a missing space in:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select *from TestTable");
```

Which should be:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TestTable");
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know which space you are talking about?

Comment: @Yasmin Then you most likely do not have a table called `TestTable`, or it needs to be quoted to be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was The table I created in db2 has schema name `"yasmin"` 
I used username and password `"db2admin/db2admin"` In JDBC connection
so it search for the table in this schema "db2admin"
so I need to set the schema to be `"yasmin"` 
so I added the following lines of code after creating
the connection

```
            String schemaName="yasmin";
            if (schemaName != null && schemaName.length() != 0) {

            try {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate("set current sqlid = " + schemaName);
                System.out.println("The schema is set successfully.");
            } catch (SQLException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
```

and grant db2admin all privilages on this table in db2

1-Right click on the table choose privilages
2-Click on "Add user" button
3-then write the username "db2admin" and click "apply" button
4-Then select the user you just add and click "gtant all" button

Now he can see the table.

Many Thanks @Mark Rotteveel and @bhamby for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting in Spring using Hibernate use following in the property line

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<database>:currentSchema=<currentSchema>;" />
```

Comment: this one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Other way is just create an ALIAS, likes this:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS USER1.YOURTABLE FOR TABLE USER2.YOURTABLE;
```