# Spring boot does not create tables from entities

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot

When I try to save an entity for the first time, I got those errors. It is spring boot.

```
lifePolicyReconciliationReceivedRepository.save(lifePolicyReconciliationReceived);
```

this is repository.

I got those errors:

```
 ARJUNA016129: Could not end XA resource com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a4@3275401a
    
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.XaException: [jcc][t4][10401][12066][4.24.92] XA exception: XA_RBROLLBACK ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
```

All fields are filled before this. Entity is this:

```
  @Entity @Table(
            schema = "CREAM" // i want to put in that schema //        , //     name = "D_RECONCILIATION_RECEIVED" // i sometimes give name, but with or without it, errors are taken

)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LifePolicyReconciliationReceived extends Serializable {

    /**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)//i also did GenerationType.IDENTITY but still error
private Long id;

private Long applicationId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date receiveDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
```

}

When i change to Id to **.IDENTITY**, it becomes:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=CREAM.D_RECONCILIATION_RECEIVED, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

WHen i create manually by going to sql, there is no problem. It can save there but why do i have to do? Spring boot can do it and connect **manytoone** and other relationships.

Because according to here
[DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919298/db2-sql-error-sqlcode-204-sqlstate-42704)

second error is for missing schema. Why doesnt it create itself?

This repository:

```
public interface LifePolicyReconciliationReceivedRepository extends JpaRepository<LifePolicyReconciliationReceived, Long> {


}
```

Normally, there was no properties file. Only yml for port. But i created and added this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

And application java file, I added this:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com/xxx/xxx/dbmodel, "com.xxxx.xxx.dataaccess""})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```

There are maven modules. I am using one of modules. So, I have to give entity path and other one is repository path.

But did not work.

Also, changed to this but still did not work:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://192.168.xx.xx:60000/FF
spring.datasource.username=qqq
spring.datasource.password=fff
```

So, when application is starting, there is not the table created. I am checking logs. So after app starts, i try to save. When repository tries to save, it gets errors.

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception.
```

Comment: is the database already created? spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update will handle with the tables, not the database itself

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida yes it is already created. Table is not. Somehow they are preventing to create it automatically.